# template template parameters on STL container

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to implement a wrapper class that uses different key-value containers such as map, unordered_map.

I hope user can use the code like this way:

```
MyWrapper<std::map> w1;
MyWrapper<std::tr1::unordered_map> w2;
```

I use **"template template paramteres"** to achieve this, 
but the template parameters of map and unordered_map is **different**..

```
// but this Wrapper is for std::map only....
template< template<typename,typename,typename,typename> class CONTAINER>
class MyWrapper
{
     CONTAINER<string, string,
            std::less<string>,
            std::allocator<std::pair<const string, string> > > c_;
};

MyWrapper<std::map> w1;
MyWrapper<std::tr1::unordered_map> w1; // not compiled!!!
```

is there any ways to make a class that can pass map or unordered_map as template parameter??
thanks!

Comment: Just have the user pass you the full type...

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use c++11 and variadic templates to do what you want:

```
template< template<typename, typename...> class CONTAINER>
```

Comment: Note that this is pretty useless, since the templates have different parameters, so you need to distinguish them anyways.

Comment: if your only concern is the key and the value, it seems to work perfectly fine.